# Improve Jython loading performance

Tags: java, jython-2.5

I have a java application which runs batch jobs. The java application calls plugins written in Python via Jython. Each plugin is initlized during the startup of the java app as follows:

```
// Prepare jython execution.
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.set("currentpath", new PyString(pySig.getParent()));
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pySig);
try
{
    interp.execfile(fis);
} finally
{
    fis.close();
}

PyFunction pyFunc = (PyFunction) interp.get("id", PyFunction.class);
```

Is there a way to improve the execfile or py loading performance? I already tried to persist or serialize the PythonInterpreter object with new success. Any speed improvment would be great since the plugins are loaded each time for a batch job.